# Add multiple integers from user input into Python list

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, tkinter

I am trying to make a simple tkinter application where the user enters an item, the quantity of the item and the unit price of said item. I want to take the sub-total of each item and store it in an array to then be calculated when the user has stopped entering items into the application.

Now my problem is I cannot get the array to store these sub-totals. It will only store one, and when the user enters another item, that item's sub-total overwrites the previous one in the list. The code I have now (that at least stores the sub-total in the array) is as follows:

```
def add():
    subtotal = int(txtUnit.get()) * int(txtQty.get())

    itemList = []
    for i in range(1):
        itemList.append(subtotal)
    print(itemList)
```

How can I get it to work so that as the user enters more items, the sub-totals will get added to the array without overwriting previous entries?

Comment: You create a new list every time: `itemList = []`

Comment: The lifetime of your `itemList` is only a single call to `add`. You need to declare it outside of that function; otherwise, it's re-initialized as empty every time `add` is called.

Comment: Also—there's *zero* need for `for i in range(1):`, since you only have one subtotal to append.

Comment: @AryaMcCarthy Thanks, that got it working